# why Sphinxapi not return result?

Tags: php, search-engine, sphinx, mariadb

I'm confused about `Sphinx`. I say about the problem. 
 My system configuration :

- `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`
- `Apache 2.4.18`
- `PHP 5.6.21`
- `MariaDB 10.1.14`
- `sphinx 2.2.10`

My database is `test2` and it contains 2 tables (documents and users) and 1 view (search).

- documents (table):

  - id
  - name
- users (table):

  - id
  - `fname`
  - `lname`
  - email
- search (view):

  - `sphinxid`
  - `itemid`
  - data
  - `datatype`

search view query is

CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `search` AS
    SELECT 
        UUID_SHORT() AS `sphinxid`,
        `users`.`id` AS `itemid`,
        CONCAT_WS(' ',
                `users`.`fname`,
                `users`.`lname`,
                `users`.`email`) AS `data`,
        1 AS `datatype`
    FROM
        `users` 
    UNION SELECT 
        UUID_SHORT() AS `sphinxid`,
        `documents`.`id` AS `itemid`,
        `documents`.`name` AS `data`,
        2 AS `datatype`
    FROM
        `documents`

Sphinx configuration file :

```
source my_search
{
        type                    = mysql

        sql_host                = localhost
        sql_user                = root
        sql_pass                = myPass
        sql_db                  = test2
        sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

        sql_query               = \
                SELECT sphinxid,itemid, data, datatype \
                FROM test2.search;


        sql_attr_uint           = itemid
        sql_attr_uint           = data
}

index test1
{
        source                  = my_search
        path                    = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test1
        morphology              = stem_en

        min_word_len            = 3
        # min_prefix_len          = 0
        # enable_star             = 0
}

searchd
{
        listen                  = 9312
        listen                  = 9306:mysql41
        log                     = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
        query_log               = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
        read_timeout            = 5
        max_children            = 30
        pid_file                = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
        # max_matches             = 1000
        seamless_rotate         = 1
        preopen_indexes         = 1
        unlink_old              = 1
        workers                 = threads # for RT to work
        binlog_path             = /var/lib/sphinxsearch
}
```

I used this command to make index `indexer --config /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf --all --rotate` . And the result is :

```
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'test1'...
collected 200 docs, 0.0 MB
total 200 docs, 200 bytes
total 0.007 sec, 28417 bytes/sec, 28417.16 docs/sec
total 2 reads, 0.000 sec, 1.5 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 10 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.6 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=2287).
```

I used `sphinxapi.php` as client `api` and my `php` test file is :

```
<?php

include '../sphinxapi.php';

if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
    var_dump($_GET['q']);
    // Build search query
    $cl = new SphinxClient();
    $cl->SetServer( "localhost", 9312 );
    $cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED  );
    $cl->SetRankingMode ( SPH_RANK_SPH04 );
    // Execute the query
    $q = '"' . $cl->EscapeString($_GET['q']) . '"/1';
    $searchresults = $cl->Query($q ,'test1');
    var_dump($cl->GetLastError());
    var_dump($cl->GetLastWarning());
}
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sphinx test 1</title>
</head>

    <body>
        <form name="search" method="get" action="">
            <input type="text" name="q" id="q" />
            <input type="submit" value="GO" class="form-submit" />
        </form>
        <p>
            <pre>
                <?php
                if(!empty($searchresults)){
                    print_r($searchresults);
                }
                ?>
            </pre>
        </p>
    </body>

</html>
```

I look at `search view` and I choose one field ( `Scarlett Downsit.fermentum@sapienimperdiet.com`) ,but when I search it (something like 'Scarlet') ,I get no result :

```
Array
(
    [error] => 
    [warning] => 
    [status] => 0
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => datatype
        )

    [attrs] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 1
            [data] => 1
        )

    [total] => 0
    [total_found] => 0
    [time] => 0.000
    [words] => Array
        (
        [scarlet] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 0
                [hits] => 0
            )

    )
)
```

Really I do not know the reason why it returns nothing ?

---

I use this command `mysql -h0 -P9306` according to sphinx tutorial.you can see in the picture that I don't have any data (you can see my query in `sphinx.conf`) and It returns 20 rows!( users table has 100 rows and documents table has 90 rows).
[image: <code>mysql -h0 -P9306</code> result]

I use this tutorial [Integrating Sphinx Search into a `PHP` Application](http://tentenstudios.com/blog/integrating-sphinx-search-php-application-part-1) but I can't get result in my Application! :(

---

When I use default `sphinx.conf` and its test database,my application works.I think my `sphinx.conf` is wrong or maybe it caused by my view (search)!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your query

```
 SELECT sphinxid,itemid, data, datatype \
            FROM test2.search;
```

Taking each in turn

- sphinxid -> automatically the `document_id` (first column)
- itemid -> made into a `uint attribute` (due to sql_attr_uint)
- data -> made into a `uint attribute` (due to sql_attr_uint)
- datatype - not mentioned, so a text `field`.

But, your view

```
... CONCAT_WS(' ', users.fname,  users.lname,  users.email) AS data, 
1 AS datatype ...
```

So looks like your actual text is in 'data', which is then stored in an integer attribute. Not going to work!

Suggests

```
    sql_attr_uint           = data
```

is a typo, and SHOULD be

```
    sql_attr_uint           = datatype
```

instead? (leaving data to be indexed as a textual field!)